# Synchronization / bootstrapping is very long

Tags: node, bootstrapping, syncing

My tezos node synchronization is very long. The question was already asked 3 years ago, the reason might have changed so I re-ask.

Right now the node is at level 2080000 (over 3025000) reached in one week.
e
But I'm now progressing at 60 blocks per minute, which mean it will take another two weeks to get fully synced.

Is it normal ? Do you have the same problems ?

More info:

- Full node
- Default sync strategy (I have not specified a syn strategy)
- 8 cores machine with 1.5 TB SSD and 64 GB ram (but I run an Ethereum node on the same machine)

Comment: Why do you need to sync from genesis instead of importing a recent (eg. a few days old) snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

As you are running in full mode, it means that you don't need the whole chain data (only a small window containing the latest ones -- see the [history modes documentation](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/history_modes.html)). Thus, you should definitively use a snapshot (see the [snapshot documentation](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html)).
In your case, your are actually downloading and validating many blocks that will be dropped right after.

Only particular services, such as block explorers, needs to gather the whole chain history and go through this very long procedure which downloads, validates and stores the whole chain history. This way of bootstrapping is known to be very long, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I want to install a block explorer that allows to go through the transactions on the blockchain but not necessarily all the past states (just list the adresses and go through the related operations). I will consider use a snapshot to speed up the sync.

Comment: Ok. If you want to get all the transaction of all blocks, you indeed need to go through the whole chain. Alternatively, if your use case is not too sensitive (or while bootstrapping your node), you should be able to find "archive tarballs" that can be downloaded from some snapshot providers.

Comment: About archive tarballs, check https://xtz-shots.io/mainnet/#archive-tarball